# counting duration with std::chrono gives 0 nanosecond when it should take long

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, timer

I was trying to count the duration taken by a for loop using std::chrono but it gives 0 nanoseconds even if i make the loop take longer by increamenting the bound value  , this is the code :

```
#pragma pack(1) // dont align let's let it take longer
struct Foo{
    int x;
    char c;
    int z;
} ;
void take_time()
{
    Foo f;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    register int c = 0;
    int x=0,y=0,z=1;
    for (c=0;c<10000;c++){ // even if i put  1000000000 it will take 0 nanosec !!!!!
        f.z = x+y;
        f.z += z-x+y;
    }
   std::cout<<"\ntoken time : "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-t1).count()<<std::endl;;
}
```

output :

```
token time : 0
```

but when i increament the bound of the loop's counter to very very huge value it suddenly takes forever !! , if i put c<100000000 it takes 0 nanosec but if i add one '0' on  the right it takes forever !!

**the answer** : 
as WhiZTiM said , the compiler is removing the loop because it does nothing useful ( thanks gcc <3 ) , but we really don't want that to happen when we are testing to algorithms to see wich one is faster on different compilers ( and not this spesific one ) , to do so we can insert an asm line into the loop . `asm("")` , an empty asm , anywhere in the loop . That will tell the compiler that there is some low level operations that he can't optimize ! , or we can use the volitile keyword for any variable used in the loop that prevents the compiler from doing any optimization related to that variable  . thanks everyone i hope this helps

Comment: x, y and z are uninitialized. Undefined behavior.

Comment: i added them later , now they are initialized but the problem persists !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, using initialized variables is [a sin.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

The Optimizer definitely figured out the loop was useless(really, what should be the values of `x`, `y`, `z` in the loop); and result of the loop wasn't used (no side effects), so it removed the loop in the generated code.

```
void take_time()
{
    Foo f;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    register int c = 0;
    int x,y,z;

    ///// Result not used
    for (c=0;c<10000;c++){ // even if i put  1000000000 it will take 0 nanosec !!!!!
        f.z = x+y;
        f.z += z-x+y;
    }
    /// We can discard the above

   std::cout<<"\ntoken time : "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-t1).count()<<std::endl;;
}
```

BTW, the `register` keyword there is deprecated.

---

For GCC and clang, there's a way to "scare" the optimizer from optimizing out the use of certain variables. I use this function:

```
template<typename T>
void scareTheOptimizer(T& x){
    asm volatile("" :: "p"((volatile void*)&x) : "memory");
}
```

So, when you call that in your loop, you should see some timing now.

```
void take_time()
{
    Foo f;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    int c = 0;
    int x=0,y=0,z=1;
    for (c=0;c<10000;c++){
        f.z = x+y;
        scareTheOptimizer(f.z);             /// <---- Added Here
        f.z += z-x+y;
    }
   std::cout<<"\ntoken time : "<< std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()-t1).count()<<std::endl;;
}
```

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b551ebdc8f45fb)

Comment: yeah i thought that way too :) , the amazing gcc is awsome XD , i added the x,y,z variables later, they are not the cause , now they are initialized but  that didn't change anything , so can you give a loop example that can't be ignored ?

Comment: thanks , and we can use also `volatile int c;`  for the loop counter , that prevents the compiler from do any optimization related to it